# Требуется по аналогии сделать новый хеш-файл из ID-компьютера

Tags: лицензирование, windows, хеширование, шифрование

Ситуация такая, есть программма, к которой надо подобрать хеш-файл, вроде бы как созданный из уникального ID компьютера (не знаю как он его создает).
В итоге у меня есть хэш-файл на комп, ID которого я знаю.
И есть мой ID, на который надо сделать по аналогии шифрования - новый хеш-файл.
Вот как-то так.

Где на форуме размещать файлы не нашел, если будет заинтересованность - ссылку дам на файлообменник.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Хеш-файл из значения.

Comment: Честно говоря - нет.

Comment: Там предлагается сделать выбор шифрования, а я его не знаю. Что делать?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/qOhJ6FccczsLr - хеш-файл готовый.   
https://yadi.sk/i/EvIUEaGHczt3p - текстовый файл с ID компьютера, с которого сделан готовый хеш-файл выше. Там же в файле расчеты хеш сумм файла,
ID для которого надо сделать хеш-файл e0fd7a7fb1c4.

Answer (score 1):

На сайте http://foxtools.ru/Hash в **Источник** вставляйте **e0fd7a7fb1c4** (кстати, а у Вас там нет случайного пробела?), затем в программе Windows Блокнот вставляйте значение полученного хэша. Сохраняйте файл с расширением **[имя].dat**. И так с каждым алгоритмом. Но если в данный файл записываются (из вашей непонятной программы) еще какие-нибудь данные - тогда беда...

Comment: Нет, пробела нет.
Если посмотреть хеш-файл - там не одна строка, как при шифровании по ссылке как вы дали.

Скорее всего как-то иначе шифруется.
Есть ли еще варианты?